# Python: access a variable in a module from another file

Tags: python

I want to access var1 and var2 in another python file where I will be using the variables in another function. How do I do this?

**file1.py**

```
def main(x):
    var1 = "link"
    var2 = "email"
```

**file2.py**

```
from file1 import var1, var2
class test:
    def get_email(self):
        return var2
    def get_link(self):
        return var1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use those variables in a separate module, you need to have the variables in the top level.

```py
var1 = ....
var2 = ....

def main(x):
    ....
```

This is because variables inside a function are local to that function and only accessible in it.

If you want to only declare the variables in the top level but assign within the function-

```py
var1 = None
var2 = None

def main(x):
    global var1
    global var2
    # assign here
```

Remember however, variables *assigned* within a function will only reflect changes *if* that function is called. Importing a module will not automatically call the function, unless the function is called at the top level *in the imported module*-

```py
var1 = None
var2 = None

def main(x):
    global var1
    global var2
    # assign here

# x should be defined prior to this
main(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

To import variables and methods from another file, you need to initialise **init**.py and **main**.py in your folder as empty files. After that you can either declare your variables you want to import on the top(outermost namespace) or return them from a function

A.py

```
myVar = 1
myString = “help”

def get_variables():
    myVar = 1
    myString = “help”
    return myVar, myString
```

B.py (first way)

```
from A import myVar, myString
```

B.py (second way)

```
from A import get_variables
myVar, myString = get_variables()
```